# Find all records that don't have any of an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using Rails 3.2.

I have a product model, and a variant model.  A product can have many variants.  A variant can belong to many products.

I want to make a lookup on the Products model, to find only products that have a specific variant count, like such (pseudocode):

`Product.where("Product.variants.count == 0")`

How do you do this with activerecord?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to return the records that you need.  Rails issues a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` when you use `includes`.

For example:

```
Product.includes(:variants).where('variants.id' => nil)
```

That will return all `products` where there are no `variants`.  You can also use an explicit `joins`.

```
Product.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN variants ON variants.product_id = products.id').where('variants.id' => nil)
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return records on the left side of the join, even if the right side is not present.  It will place `null` values into the associated columns, which you can then use to check negative presence, as I did above.  You can read more about left joins here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp.

The good thing about this solution is that you're not doing subqueries as a conditional, which will most likely be more performant.

Comment: This seems like the correct way to go about it, but for some reason my `Spree::Product.includes(:variants).where('variants.id' => nil)` returns an error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "variants", LINE 1: ...' AND "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "variants"...`

Comment: It looks like the table name should be `spree_variants` instead of `variants`.  You can either change that first example to `.where('spree_variants.id' => nil)`, or you can do `.where(Variant.arel_table[:id].eq(nil))`.  Just make sure that wherever you have `variants`, you have `spree_variants` because Rails engines prefix the table names with the engine name.

Answer (score 1):

```
products= Product.find(:all,:select => 'variant').select{|product| product.varients.count > 10}
```

This is rails 2.3 , but only the activeRecord part, you need to see the `select` part

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any ActiveRecord way to do this but the following should help with your problem.  The good thing about this solution is that everything's done on the db side.

```
Product.where('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM variants WHERE variants.product_id = products.id) > 0')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pull products which have a specific non-0 number of variants, you could do that with something like this (admittedly untested):

```
Product.select('product.id, product.attr1_of_interest, ... product.attrN_of_interest, variant.id, COUNT(*)')
       .joins('variants ON product.id = variants.product_id')
       .group('product.id, product.attr1_of_interest, ... product.attrN_of_interest, variant.id')
       .having('COUNT(*) = 5')  #(or whatever number manipulation you want to do here)
```

If you want to allow for 0 products, you would have to use Sean's solution above.

Comment: I see your title says "that don't have any" even though your question said "specific variant count", so this is an extra credit answer, I guess :).

Comment: +1 for actually reading the body of the post.  I just went with the title and the pseudocode example and provided the answer based on those.